# Sewage smell in my basement - Where is it coming from?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, smell, sewer

I have been randomly getting these periods of time(a day or so) where I enter my basement and I get hit by a strong wave of what I think is sewage gas. I recently replaced the wax ring underneath the toilet in the bathroom(which did have a slight leak prior to putting a new wax ring). I checked to make sure that it wasn't leaking again and it seems fine. There is a little Crawl-space next to the bathroom downstairs that has the main sewage line access but it looks fine. The only other thing I can think of is the floor drain for the water heater and furnace condensation.

Here are some of the things I am suspicious of: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When is the last time any water has been down that drain?   Any little-used sinks or toilets?

Answer (score 3):

You want to make sure that all your traps have water in them.  If your floor drain is dry, it will leak sewer gas.  Also, if you have natural gas or propane, check to make sure that there are no leaks.  Natural gas can smell like sewer gas.

Comment: I would dump some water in the trap to make sure. I have seen homes that developed the same problem when birds built a nest on the vent pipe and when the bath tub drained it sucked the water or most of the water out of the trap there was enough water in the trap until an exhaust fan in the upstairs kitchen was turned on the negative pressure was enough to pull the sewer gas in took a while to solve that one.

Comment: Any tips on where I can find the trap?

Comment: @aguertin pour a pitcher of water down all drains that are not regularly used, and do it every few weeks.